# "We look forward to assisting you"

Tags: expressions

I'm working on translating a script for a service desk, but I'm stumped at finding an equivalent for the ending phrase "we look forward to assisting you". What would you advise to be a good translation that sounds natural?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't there a formula like *Nous restons/sommes à votre disposition...* ? It doesn't translate the phrase literally but it is found in the same scenarios.

Comment: This is what I went with. I was actually looking to translate the phrase in Spanish as well, and went with the equivalent rephrasing of the idea.

Answer (score 7):

**"Dans l'attente de..."** is a sentence commonly used at the end of an email (more or less a translation of "We look forward to..."), so I guess **"Dans l'attente de pouvoir vous aider/de pouvoir vous apporter notre aide"** would fit as a literal translation, but is still a bit formal (but hey, maybe that's what you're searching for :) ).

However I'm also thinking of other solutions that sounds maybe a bit more natural:

- **"En espérant pouvoir vous aider au plus vite"** (if the problem is not resolved yet but you need additional information to solve it)
- **"En espérant pouvoir à nouveau vous aider à l'avenir"** (if the problem is solved but you're offering your help in the future if needed)
- **"En espérant avoir pu vous aider"** (the problem should be solved, but this implies you're waiting the person to confirm it's solved)

Note: if you want to get rid of any formal stuff, you can also replace "En espérant" by "J'espère/Nous espérons" in the above sentences. It gives the feeling an actual person is talking, instead of an expression, it depends on the context and what you're looking for I guess.

Comment: I have never seen this express so far. I more used to see `Je/nous reste/ons à votre entière disposition pour toute remarque/demande/aide ... ...`. Is it not the usage ?

Comment: Yes, yours is perfectly correct as well ;) Just another way of saying it

Answer (score 0):

It can be translated by: Nous nous ferons un plaisir de vous aider/assister.